# Значение __ в php скрипте

Tags: php, wordpress, веб-программирование

Открыл `C:\OSPanel\domains\digitalelectronics.ru\wp-content\plugins\elementor\core\document-types\page.php`

```html
<?php
namespace Elementor\Core\DocumentTypes;

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

class Page extends PageBase {
    public static function get_properties() {
        $properties = parent::get_properties();

        $properties['cpt'] = [ 'page' ];
        $properties['support_kit'] = true;

        return $properties;
    }

    /**
     * @access public
     */
    public function get_name() {
        return 'wp-page';
    }

    /**
     * @access public
     * @static
     */
    public static function get_title() {
        return __( 'Page', 'elementor' );
    }
}
```

Что в функции `get_title` означает символ __?

Comment: Там два символа - два подчеркивания.

Comment: Ознакомься наконец https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. Особенно c п3.

Answer (score 1):

Есть такая библиотека - [GetText](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gettext) и в ней функция _ (да, одно нижнее подчеркивание) используется для организации переводов. То есть, функция по заданому ключу (английской строке) выдает строку на нужном языке (согласно конфигу).

В Wordpress пошли по такому же пути и определили функцию с двумя подчеркиваниями - она просто смотри в файл переводов и отдает подходящую строку. Детали - в [сорцах](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/l10n.php#L288).

Answer (score 1):

Есть ряд функций для локализации тем и плагинов, которые используя текст в качестве параметра и файл перевода, возвращают результат обработки

Функция

```
__( 'Page', 'elementor' );
```

возвращает перевод текста "Page", используя файл перевода 'elementor'

Список всех функций https://wp-kama.ru/function-cat/lokalizatsiya

Пример создания переводов плагинов и тем https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/internationalization/